# exceltex dependencies in latexmk

Tags: latexmk, exceltex

I'm working on getting [exceltex](http://www.physik.uni-freiburg.de/~doerr/exceltex/index.en.html#probs) and `latexmk` communicating by adding custom dependencies to `.latexmkrc`.

As far as I understand, `exceltex` works by writing an entry for each `\inctab`/`inccell` command to an `excltx` file upon compilation, and the using the `Perl` script `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` to extract information from the `.xls` file. The manual routine: `latexmk`, `exceltex`, `latexmk`, and it works. So I believe I need the following dependency relations:

1. `excltex` and `xls`: if the `xls` file is changed, `exceltex` is invoked.
2. `excltex` and `tex`: if the `tex` file with `\inccell`/`\inctab` calls changes, `exceltex` is invoked.

As I have understood, `latexmk` doesn't handle multiple files in one dependency, so I first focused on getting #2 working. I have tried:

```
add_cus_dep('excltx', 'tex', 0, 'excel2tex');
    sub excel2tex {
        system("exceltex \"$_[0].tex\"") ;
    }
```

which makes `latexmk` generate the following output:

```
For rule 'cusdep excltx tex test', running '&do_cusdep(  )' ...
Latexmk: Possible misconfiguration or bug:
  In trying to apply custom-dependency rule
  to make 'test.tex' from 'test.excltx'
  the function name is blank.
```

My intention is that the dependency will trigger `exceltex file.tex`. Why doesn't this happen? How can I change my dependency such that it will run `exceltex`?

Follow up:
Assuming the above dependency works (which it does after commenting out all other dependencies in `.latexmkrc`, running `latexmk` and uncommenting the pacified dependencies), how can I make `latexmk` run `exceltex` when the `xls` file is changed? I have tried with

```
add_cus_dep('tex', 'xls', 0, 'excel2tex');
```

and

```
add_cus_dep('excltx', 'xls', 0, 'excel2tex');
```

(and both, for good measure). It works if I force a complete recompilation. With a normal compilation, where the content of the `tex` document is untouched but the `xls` file is changed, `latexmk` refuses to notice a change in just the `xls` file.

Comment: Updated question! And here: http://www.physik.uni-freiburg.de/~doerr/exceltex/index.en.html#probs

Comment: With your definitions, it should work. However, in the output listing, I see `&do_cusdep(  )` reported, whereas it should be `&do_cusdep( excel2tex )` given your custom dependency's definition.  Here are some possibilities: (a) The code in `latexmkrc` is not identical to the code in the question. (b) Something else in one of your `latexmkrc` files messes with the relevant `latexmk` internals.  (c) Your `latexmk` is not a standard one. (d) A bug in `latexmk`, although I cannot reproduce it.  What happens if the custom dependency is the only thing in any of the `latexmkrc` files?

Comment: @JohnCollins I have two other dependencies, the [`gnuplot` dependency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106512/gnuplot-in-latex-without-gnuplottex) and an [`nomencl` dependency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105943/latexmk-and-nomencl). Commenting out all dependencies and running `latexmk` made the `excel2tex` dependency run. Afterwords I made sure that my other dependencies still work. [Dafuq?](http://i1.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/290/698/c3e.jpg)

Comment: @Holene This is quite strange.  It might be best to debug the problem off-line, and then report the results here. My e-mail is in the `latexmk` documentation.  Send a minimal example that shows the problem (complete `latexmkrc` files and `tex` files), and we can take it from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the difficulty about a "Possible misconfiguration or bug" cannot now be reproduced, we can ignore that part of the question for the moment.  I'll answer the rest of the question, which is how to make a custom dependency that will be run if the `xls` file changes.  Here is a suitable tested code for a `latexmkrc` file:

```
add_cus_dep('excltx', 'tex', 0, 'excel2tex');
sub excel2tex {
    # First find dependency/ies on .xls files, by parsing the .excltx file,
    my $Hsource = new FileHandle;
    my %xls = ();
    my $source = "$_[0].excltx";
    if (! open $Hsource, "<$source") {
        warn "excel2tex subroutine: Could not read '$source'\n";
        return 1;
    }
    while ( <$Hsource> ) {
        if ( /^\s*;/ ) { next; }
        if ( /^\s*[ct]:[^:]*\:([^!]*)!/ ) { $xls{$1} = 1; }
    }
    close $Hsource;
    foreach (keys %xls) {
        rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $_ );
    }
    return system("exceltex \"$_[0]\"") ;
}
```

The functioning is as follows: The main `tex` file uses the package `exceltex` to use the contents of cells in an `xls` spreadsheet.  It does this by writing a specification of the cells to a file with extension `excltx`.  The script `exceltex` reads this, extracts the data from the spreadsheet(s), and writes them in files that are read during the next compilation of the main document.  (The `exceltex` package, with its script, is part of the current version of TeXLive.)

In addition to running the `exceltex` script, the subroutine defined above also reads the `excltx` file to find the names of the spreadsheet files used.  It then uses an internal subroutine of `latexmk` to add these files to the source-file list of the custom dependency.  Thus if the spreadsheet file (or files) changes even without any other changes, `latexmk` will know to rerun `exceltex` and then recompile the main `tex` file if necessary.