# gnuplot in LaTeX with Pdflatex, without gnuplottex

Tags: pdftex, gnuplot

I wonder if it is possible to find an analogical solution for `pdflatex` instead of `latex`, see [gnuplot in LaTeX, without gnuplottex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106512/gnuplot-in-latex-without-gnuplottex).

Changing the `gnuplot` code to:

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions= pdf input]
     set samp 100;
     set iso 40;
     set xrange [0:1];
     set yrange [0:1];
     set zrange [0.8:2];
     unset key;
     unset colorbox;
     set hidden3d front;
     a = 1;
     set xyplane at a;
     f(x,y) = (x+y)/(2*sqrt(x*y));
     set xlabel "$\\tau_I$";
     set ylabel "$\\tau_D$";
     set zlabel "$\\zeta$";
     set output "figures/cascade.tex"
     splot f(x,y) with pm3d at b, f(x,y) with lines;
     unset output
\end{gnuplot}
```

and compiling with `pdflatex` (`-shell-escape` is enable) not only the `.pdf` and `.tex` files from `cairolatex` in path figures but also in Tex path root (`thesis.tex`) `thesis-gnuplottex-fig1.gnuplot` and `thesis-gnuplottex-fig1.tex` (0 bytes) are produced. The `.gnuplot` file can be deleted by writing `cleanup` in `gnuplottex` options. Nonetheless, the `thesis.pdf` document contents the plot, as desired.
If it is possible to define a similar "custom dependency" for `pdflatex`? May be in the command line of `pdflatex`?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround to solve this problem with my basic `latex` skills taking into account a similar solution for Inkscape, see sub-subsection *3.3.2. LATEX code* in page 3 of [How to include an SVG image in LATEX](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) by Johan B. C. Engelen in 2013.

Files structure:

```
  /main/
        |-- main.tex
        |-- macros/
                     |-- newcommands.tex
        |-- content/
                     |-- chapter.tex
        |-- images/
                     |-- gnuplot/
                                 |-- cascade.plt
                     |-- figures/ 
                                 |-- cascade.tex
                                 |-- cascade.pdf
```

Follow these steps (Windows 7, Gnuplot, `Miktex`,TexStudio, and `Pdflatex`):

1. Add `-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18` to the command line when calling pdflatex:
   `pdflatex.exe -enable-write18 -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
2. Add the `gnuplot.exe` windows path directory to the additional search paths in commands ($Path).
   For example, in my case: `C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin`
3. Following packages are required: `import` ([Establish input relative to a directory](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import)) and `filemod` ([Pro­vide file mod­i­fi­ca­tion times, and com­pare them](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filemod)). You have to add them in your preamble:
   `\usepackage{import, filemod-expmin}`
4. The `/main/images/gnuplot/cascade.plt` file contains:

   ```
     cd 'images\figures'
     set terminal cairolatex pdf input
     set output 'cascade.tex'
     set dummy u, v
     set parametric
     set isosamples 21, 21
     set hidden3d back offset 1 trianglepattern 3 undefined 1 altdiagonal bentover
     set style data lines
     set title "Real part of complex square root function" 
     set urange [ -3.00000 : 3.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
     set vrange [ -3.00000 : 3.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
     splot u**2-v**2,2*u*v,u notitle
     unset output
   ```
5. Add the following code to the preamble of your document (for example, in my case: `/main/macros/newcommands.tex`):

   ```
      \newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{%
         \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}%
             {\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0% 
             {#3}%
         \fi%
      }
      \newcommand{\includegnu}[1]{%
          \IfFileExists{images/gnuplot/#1.plt}{%
             \IfFileExists{images/figures/#1.tex}{%
                 \executeiffilenewer{images/gnuplot/#1.plt}{images/figures/#1.tex}{\immediate\write18{gnuplot images/gnuplot/#1.plt}}}{%
                 \immediate\write18{gnuplot images//gnuplot//#1.plt}}%
                 \subimport{images/figures/}{#1.tex}}%
          {\errmessage{LaTeX Error: 'images/gnuplot/#1.plt' not found, input line \the\inputlineno}}%
      }
   ```
6. When an image is included via `\includegnu`, it is automatically exported to `Pdflatex` again by `Gnuplot` when the `.plt` file has changed (note that the image must be specified without file extension):

   ```
           \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering
                \includegnu{cascade}
                \caption[My caption]{The caption}
                \label{fig:fig_11}
           \end{figure}
   ```

Are there any other possibilities to improve these codes? May be the `newcommands`?

Or other possible solutions?

Thank you in advance